# Total totals not coming in correctly

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am attempting to get the total of the meters for each type along with the estimated meters for each type, but the total does not come in correctly.

```
SELECT  AMI_YEAR, AMI_MONTH,
    COUNT(ACCOUNT_NO) as TOTal_Bills,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Device_Type = 'AMI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN Device_Type = 'OTHER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Estimated,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Device_Type = 'AMI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
               AMI_Estimated,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Device_Type = 'OTHER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 
              NON_AMI_Estimated
FROM 
          (SELECT DISTINCT 
                   A.GL_PERIOD AS AMI_MONTH,
                   A.GL_YEAR AS AMI_YEAR,
                   A.ACCOUNT_NO,
                   CASE WHEN X.DEVICE_TP = 'AMI' THEN 'AMI' ELSE 'OTHER' END 
                      AS Device_Type
                 FROM  A 
                       INNER JOIN  B ON A.ACCOUNT_NO = B.ACCOUNT_NO AND CONVERT(DATE,A.BILL_RUN_DT,101) = CONVERT(DATE,B.BILL_RUN_DT,101)
                       INNER JOIN  C ON A.ACCOUNT_NO = C.ACCOUNT_NO AND A.LOCATION_NO = C.LOCATION_NO AND CONVERT(DATE,A.BILL_RUN_DT,101) = CONVERT(DATE,C.BILLED_DTM,101)
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN  X ON C.SERIAL_NO = 
                         X.DEVICE_SERIAL_NO
                 WHERE A.ESTIMATED_YN = 'T' 
                 AND   A.GL_YEAR      >= YEAR(GETDATE())-1
                 AND   B.VOIDED_YN    = 'F'
                 )Z
GROUP BY  AMI_YEAR, AMI_MONTH
ORDER BY  AMI_YEAR, AMI_MONTH
```

will return all the information for estimated meters, but not the total of the meters, ex for one row:
Year, AMI_MONTH, Total_BILLS, TOTAL_ESTIMATED, AMI_ESTIMATED, NON_AMI ESTIMATED
2017, 1, 695, 695, 0, 695

I also need the total of ami meters and a total of non_ami meters (estimated + non estimated for each type). When I try to add something like: DEVICE_TYPE, COUNT (*) AS TYPE to the main or the sub query it fails.

How do I get the current results and the total of all ami and all non-ami meters? An over-all total  for each type would be nice too, but can be computed easily enough.

Comment: I tried to line up the query to be easier to understand, but it kept realigning to the current view

Comment: I don't understand why your totals are not correct.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: It looks to me like the totals from the main query are coming strictly from the sub query, so I can only act on the data coming back from it, but I can't add a total to the sub query without it failing. I can't add the total in the from statement outside the sub query without it failing either. Or  I'm not adding it correctly which is most likely.

Comment: In general, if you want a column's data to appear in your output it either has to be part of an aggregation or grouped by that value. Any precise answer may depend on your DBMS (and the actual table itself) - consider using http://sqlfiddle.com/ or similar to build data people can test solutions against.